# Unable to add default route via VPN (openvpn)

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn, vpn

Initially my routing table looks like this

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp3s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
```

After I connect to company's network using VPN, server pushes some routes and table looks like this

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
X.X.X.X         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    50     0        0 vpn0
X.X.X.X         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    50     0        0 vpn0
........ and so on .....
```

I want to default all traffic via VPN and issue following commands

```
sudo route del default
sudo route add default dev vpn0
```

they complete with no errors and in kern.log I see the following:

```
Jan  5 22:04:45 thinkpad NetworkManager[1079]: <info>  [1546715085.3821] policy: set 'vpn0' (vpn0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
```

But no default route appears in table and ping says Network unreachable.

If I tick the option "ignore automatically obtained routes" finally after connection I get default route via vpn0. But I can't delete it (**sudo route del default vpn0** in various combinations makes no sense).

The idea is that I want to route traffic via VPN or via WiFi on the fly and without disconnection. And wonder why I can't.

PS: I've tried all of this using **ip route** with the same effect

OpenVPN and kernel I have:

```
network-manager-openvpn/xenial-updates,now 1.1.93-1ubuntu1.1 amd64 [installed]
openvpn/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 2.3.10-1ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed]

Linux thinkpad 4.4.0-53-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: `ip addr flush dev vpn0` should be useful.

Comment: It removes all automatically added routes but still can't add default route manually.